# For unpolarized plane wave traveling normal incident from air to dielectric what are the reflection and transmission coefficients?

Tags: polarization, dielectric, plane-wave

Given an unpolarized plane wave traveling in air and hitting a dielectric at normal incident what equations can be used to calculate the reflection and transmission coefficient? I know for a polarized planes that there are equations consisting only of n1 and n2. But I am unsure what to do when the plane waves are unpolarized. I feel like it should be simpler than what is happening in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the dielectric material is anisotropic, light incident at 90 degrees to the surface has the same reflectivity for any polarization.  This should be clear from the fact that the dielectric has no "identifiable" orientation.  If you had a nonlinear crystal, then the behavior would depend on the orientation of the fast and slow axes, and the percentage of the input light which is polarized in one axis or the other (keeping in mind you can break any vector into 2 orthogonal components).

Answer (score 1):

The amplitude reflection coefficients as calculated from the Fresnel formulae. There's one for s-pol, and one for p-pol, and at normal incidence one might expect them to be the same, but there is a sign convention to watch out for, and they might have opposite signs depending on where you are getting the formulae.

Reflectivity for unpolarized light is the average reflectivity of s and p:
$$ R = (r_s^*r_s + r_p^*r_p)/2   $$and similar for $T$, assuming, of course, no absorption or scattering.   Either sign convention will get the same answer.  At normal incidence the reflectivity is the same for s and p (assuming isotropic, etc), so you get $$R = r_s^*r_s $$